# Dynamic drag constrainTo in jquery.pep.js

Tags: jquery, constraints, drag

Question is about the `constrainTo` option in the plug-in [jquery.pep.js](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js).

**tl,dr:** How do I dynamically assign `constrainTo` to be an arbitrary jQuery element?

**Example:** In the code below I have nested div's: pep-grandparent > pep-parent > pep. In the initialization `$('.pep').pep()` I would like to assign `constrainTo` to pep's 'grandparent' element, of class pep-grandparent. Since the grandparent size can change, I want a dynamic assignment of `constrainTo`.

The [documented](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js) option for `constrainTo` is 'parent' or an array [top, right, bottom, left]. Naively I passed an *in situ* calculation for the array. However I observe that this assignment is applied only on initialization of `.pep()`. If I resize the browser (note the % width spec in css - an artifice for dynamic behavior) the pep remains constrained to its old `constrainTo`. However, if the `constrainTo` happened to be 'parent' (i.e; the pep-parent element) the constraint is indeed dynamic.

I tried to read the [source](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js/blob/master/src/jquery.pep.js) but I'm not a Javascript ninja, so didn't mess around there.

**Question 1:** Is it possible to assign another jQuery element to `constrainTo`?

**Question 2**: Can I re-assign `constrainTo` in (say) the drag `initiate`? If so, how do I do this?

**Question 3**: Opinion invited on this hack solution: set `constrainTo` to `false` and handle the constraint logic in the drag `initiate/start/move/stop`. I tried this, it works, but somehow I feel the native `constrainTo` is more smooth.

Note: I've freely mixed up html classes and id's in the code - sloppy, but ok for this example.

**html**

```
   <div id='pgp1' class='pep-grandparent'>
     <div id='pp1' class='pep-parent'>
       <div id='p1' class='pep'></div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**css**

```
.pep-grandparent {
    background: white;
    height: 400px;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.pep-parent {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 30%;
}

.pep {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

**js**

```
 $('.pep').pep({
            constrainTo: function(){
                var $p = $('#p1');     //pep element
                var $pGP = $('#pgp1');  //pep-grandparent element
                var top = $pGP.offset()['top'];
                var right = $pGP.offset()['left'] + $pGP.width() - $p.width();
                var bottom = $pGP.offset()['top'] + $pGP.height() - $p.height();
                var left = $pGP.offset()['left'];
                return [top, right, bottom, left];
            }(),
            //**OPTION** constrainTo: 'parent',
            useCSSTranslation: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to be able to change the constrainTo dynamically as well.  Here is how I did it:

```
$('.pep').data('plugin_pep').options.constrainTo = [top, right, bottom, left];
```

There is not a nice way to access the constraints once you call the plugin.  But you can access the pep object through the element data and change it like that, and it works.  You just need to update the constrainTo property each time your constraints change.